# Spawn python ENOENT in node.js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I am creating a node js script that interacts with both python and electron js to create a GUI. I am currently stuck at an error unfortunately. That error being:

```
Uncaught Error: spawn python ENOENT
```

This is on line 167 of events.js, a script that I have not been able to find. I have currently set my PYTHON env variable to C:\Python27\python.exe and my PYTHONPATH to C:\Python27.

Here is the code that is being run when this error occurs.

```
function getselectors() {
var ps = require("python-shell")
var path = require("path")

var amount = document.getElementById('para').value;

var options = {
    scriptPath : path.join (__dirname, '/../engine/'), args : [amount]
}

ps.PythonShell.run ('test.py', options, function (err, results) {
if (err) throw err;
swal (results [0]);
});
```

}